# Javascript playground from URL or with all data in the HTTP request?

Tags: javascript

I'd like to provide interactive examples in the documentation for [Parsley](http://parsleyjs.org/), a jQuery extension to validate forms.

Ideally, this would use a resource like `jsfiddle` or `codepen`, but I'd like the code to come from the doc itself. Both `jsfiddle` and `codepen` require you to edit your examples on their page and provide only an ID at the end.

I would dream of being able to use a URL like `http://some-code-pen-clone.com?load_from=<url to html>`

This would open a code pen with stuff in `<script>` put the in code section or external resources, the `<body>` would be the HTML.

From there the user can modify the source, fork, etc...

Is there such a resource?

This is for open source, as such I'd rather not spend more than ~100 USD on this...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Actually, [CodePen](http://codepen.io/) has a [nifty interface](https://blog.codepen.io/documentation/api/prefill/) to populate the HTML, JS and CSS of a playground. For example, click on the 'CodePen' button [in this example](http://parsleyjs.org/doc/examples/customvalidator.html)

I discovered later that [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net) also [has a similar interface](http://doc.jsfiddle.net/api/post.html).

Comment: Nice! I didn't know CodePen had that functionality.

Answer (score 1):

You can use [Github Gists](http://gist.github.com/) :)

[This Github repo](https://github.com/mikethedj4/Code-Playground--Save-Code-As-Gist) allows you to save your code as a github gist and retrieve that code via `window.location.hash`.

That's actually how you save weaves on [kodeWeave](http://kodeweave.sourceforge.net/editor/#295f01c3cde925ddd20cf770ee32083f).

I got the inspiration from [Dabblet](http://dabblet.com/).

For example you can save your weave like this...

```
// Save code online as github gist
$("[data-action=save]").click(function() {
  var htmlVal = htmlEditor.getValue()
  var cssVal  = cssEditor.getValue()
  var jsVal   = jsEditor.getValue()

  var data = {
    // Description of the gist
    "description": "My exported snippet",
    // public or private?
    "public": true,
    // This gist has a html file, named index.html
    "files": {
      "index.html": {
        "content": htmlVal
      },
      "style.css": {
        "content": cssVal
      },
      "script.js": {
        "content": jsVal
      }
    }
  }
  // Post on Github via JQuery Ajax
  $.ajax({
    url: "https://api.github.com/gists",
    type: "POST",
    dataType: "json",
    data: JSON.stringify(data)
  })
  .success(function(e) {
    window.location.hash = e.html_url.split("https://gist.github.com/").join("")
    hash = window.location.hash.replace(/#/g,"")
    $("[data-action=saved]").text(document.referrer + "#" + hash)
    $("[data-action=saved]").attr("href", document.referrer + "#" + hash)
                            .attr("target", "_blank")
  })
  .error(function(e) {
    console.warn("gist save error", e)
    $("[data-action=saved]").text("gist save error", e)
  })
})
```

and in order to load a weave you saved online you can do it like this via `window.location.hash`...

```
// Retrieve github gist and load in editor
var hash = window.location.hash.substring(1);;
if (window.location.hash) {
  function loadgist(gistid) {
    $.ajax({
      url: "https://api.github.com/gists/" + gistid,
      type: "GET",
      dataType: "jsonp",
      jsonp: "callback"
    }).success(function(gistdata) {
      var htmlVal = gistdata.data.files["index.html"]
      var cssVal  = gistdata.data.files["style.css"]
      var jsVal   = gistdata.data.files["script.js"]

      // Return the editor's values
      if (!htmlVal) {
        htmlEditor.setValue("")
      } else {
        htmlEditor.setValue(htmlVal.content)
      }
      if (!cssVal) {
        cssEditor.setValue("")
      } else {
        cssEditor.setValue(cssVal.content)
      }
      if (!jsVal) {
        jsEditor.setValue("")
      } else {
        jsEditor.setValue(jsVal.content)
      }
    }).error(function(e) {
      // ajax error
      console.warn("Error: Could not load code!", e)
      alertify.error("Error: Could not load code!")
    })
  }

  loadgist(hash)
}
```

Comment: Thanks, but I don't want to store the examples elsewhere than in the code. Moreover I don't think gists have built-in preview?
I had forgotten to post an answer that fulfills what I wanted, just did it. Thanks